# Numbers, Units, and Measurements

Tags: numbers, measure-expressions

When it comes to measuring quantities, we say 1 L of water, 1 gallon of gasoline, or 1 kW of power.

Is it correct if I rearrange the words by exchanging the position of the unit and their quantities?

For example, is "water of 1 L" the same as "1 L of water"?

Is "power of 1 kW" the same as "1 kW of power"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of kilowatt (kW), three forms appear:
The device dissipates 1 kW of power.
The device dissipates a power of 1 kW.
The device dissipates 1 kW. (power is implied by the name of the unit)

You can verify that all three forms appear by searching for them, in the Google search bar and at Google books.  The same forms appear for current (ampere or A), and to some degree for EMF (voltage or V).

In the case of (water of 1 L) or (gasoline of 1 gallon), those forms are very rare, and should not be used.

The safest form to use is the one that appears in a textbook.